# Eliminar todos los espacios en blanco de un elemento HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo etiquetas  las cuales como texto tienen enlaces a webs, es decir, algo como esto.

```
<a href="http://www.asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.com/asdfassdfasdf....">http://www.asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.com/asdfassdfasdf....</a>
```

El problema que tengo es que al hacer la pagina responsive esta se desborda, ya que las URL son muy largas (las etiquetas  son mas anchas que el contenedor).

He probado a introducir un espacio en las URL con lo cual el problema al reducir el tamaño del display en que se visualice esta desaparece, pero claro como he introducido un espacio, si el display es mas grande dicho espacio se ve.

Entonces el tema es el siguiente: ¿Hay alguna propiedad CSS que permita eliminar todos los espacios en blanco del texto de una etiqueta y asi evitar tener que quitar estos con JS?

Comment: Sería ideal que pusieras un [mcve] en la pregunta (con cadenas/urls de prueba) para que podamos ver el problema y ayudarte con el problema concreto que tengas.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta de @EduenSarceño si solucionó tu inquietud... esto es importante para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 4):

No hace falta que agregues espacios, basta con definir la propiedad `overflow-wrap` en `break-word`

```css
.etiqueta {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal !important
}
```

```html
<span class="etiqueta">data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAIAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAJgAAACAgAAABACAAqBAAAI4EAAAoAAAAEAAAACAAAAABACAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqaOe/6mjnv+po57/qaOe/6mjnv+po57/qaOe/6mjnv+po57</span>
<hr />
<span class="etiqueta wrap">data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAIAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAJgAAACAgAAABACAAqBAAAI4EAAAoAAAAEAAAACAAAAABACAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqaOe/6mjnv+po57/qaOe/6mjnv+po57/qaOe/6mjnv+po57</span>
```

Comment: Gracias, no conocía la propiedad overflow-wrap y consultado la W3schools no la he encontrado. Ahora funciona perfectamente solo añadiendo esa linea en el CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que necesitas es:

[text overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Tienes una prueba [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mbrsh2g4/)

Si utilizas % en el max width, puedes hacerlo responsive